# Can be a transition matrix of homogeneous Markov's Chain to be disjoint in t?

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, transition-matrix

Can be a transition matrix of homogeneous Markov's Chain to be discontonuous of  $t$, if $P(X_τ = j∣X_{t_n} = i_n, X_{t_n−1} = i_{n−1}, . . . , X_{t_1} = i_1) = P(X_τ = j∣X_{t_n} = i_n)$ $\forall t_1<t_2<...<t_n<\tau$ $\forall i_1, i_2...,i_n, j \in \{1...r\}$?

Comment: I do not understand the question.  It looks like you are stating the definition of a Markov chain.  I do not know what "disjoint in $t$" means.

Comment: @Michael, it was a language problem, sry

Comment: I think you are asking, for a (time homogeneous) Continuous Time Markov Chain (CTMC) $X(t)$ with finite state space $S$, if we fix $i,j \in S$, is the following function continuous in $t$? $$f_{ij}(t) = P[X(t)=j|X(0)=i]$$  The answer is "yes." In fact the $f_{ij}(t)$ functions are both continuous and differentiable. There are standard ways to write a system of linear ODEs that express $f_{ij}'(t)$ in terms of $(f_{ij}(t))$.  A google search such as "ODE for CTMC" will find more info.